# Appending a filename before the extension with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to modify a file name just before the extension, in this case.

So, for example the file is called `image1.jpg` and I would like to upload it as `image1_thumbnail.jpg`.

Currently the code places `thumbnail_` at the beginning so it outputs `thumbnail_image1.jpg` but I need it at the end.

I am using at the moment…

```
<cfimage action="resize"
  height="#thumbHeight#"
  width="#thumbWidth#"
  source="#uploadedImage#"
  destination="#MediaPath#/thumbs/thumbnail_#file.serverFile#"
  overwrite="true"/>

<cfoutput> 
<img src="photos/thumbs/thumbnail_#file.serverFile#" 
  height="#thumbHeight#" width="#thumbWidth#" align="left" hspace="10">
```

Any ideas very much appreciated.

Comment: Check [the documentation for cffile action=upload](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-738f.html). `cffile.serverFile` is not the only variable available. It also returns the file name and extension *separately*. With the right variables you could easily build the desired file name. Side note, `FILE` is deprecated. Either use `cffile` or use the "result" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat file.serverfile as a period delimited list.

```
destination = ListFirst(file.serverfile, '.') 
& "_thumbnail." 
& ListRest(file.serverfile, '.')
```

Comment: What about file names that contain more than one `.` (period)? I don't think there is an issue with your answer but the OP needs to be aware of the outcome in that scenario.

Comment: Simpler to skip list functions and use `cffile.serverFileName` and `cffile.serverFileExt`.

Comment: Using ListRest instead of ListLast might take care of that.  The OP can sort that out.

Comment: I agree with Leigh.  I think she should submit her comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per Leigh's suggestion, this is probably easier done with something like this:

```
<cfset thumbfileName = cffile.serverFileName & "_thumbnail." & cffile.serverFileExt>

...
destination="#MediaPath#/thumbs/#variables.thumbfileName#"
...

...
<img src="photos/thumbs/#variables.thumbfileName#" ...
```